# Data file in ADM won't respond

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if database is appearing on data file through a tutorial to make my own database. 
In the tutorial the guy asks to go to Tools-->Android-->Android Device Monitor and from then to select Device, and the project should be appearing

**Android Device Monitor show :**

[image]

But my projects are not appearing under my device (Lenovo Tablet)
and I have tapped 7 times on Build Number, and debugg USB.
but still when I click data file it will not respond and will not open.

(p.s i can run apps on my tablet still)

Help anyone?

Comment: if your phone is not rooted of course it will show nothing to you. Root your device and try again

Comment: It's a tablet not  phone, and read again you'll see I've followed the steps

Comment: read again yourself...Your device needs to be ROOTED to see the data/data/package folder....It does not matter whether its a phone or tablet